# Probability density function for Riemann-zeta zeros

Tags: probability-theory, riemann-zeta

Curious about the expected probability distribution for the spacing between Riemann zeta zeros, of the form $s_n=\sigma+it_n$, where $\sigma=0.5$ and $t_n$ is the imaginary part of the $n$-th zero.

The mean spacing between zeros decreases slowly as the height $t_n$ goes up, somewhat confounding the issue, but taking a narrow slice of 100,000 zeros starting at the billionth zero ($t_{1000000000}$) should make that variation negligible. Here's a histogram of the spacings in that region:
[image]

The longer upper tail precludes a normal distribution. The red curve is a best fit gamma distribution, which doesn't quite do it either. The mean spacing at the beginning of the range covered is $0.351087$ compared to $0.351073$ at the end, so that variation is small.

What is the closest distribution to model the spacing?

Comment: The zeros conjectured to have the same distribution as the eigenvalues of a random Hermitian matrix, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montgomery%27s_pair_correlation_conjecture. That implies a lot about the spacing between zeros (in particular the fact that the distribution peaks away from zero is related to the tendency for eigenvalues to repel one another). I don't know enough about the topic to post an answer, but this and this (http://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/mrwatkin/zeta/random.htm) should be a good starting point to learn more.

Answer (score 2):

I've done five million spacings starting from billionth (1e9) zero, and find that from the distribution I had in use Nakagami had highest log-likelihood.[image: Five million consecutive spacings at 1e9 with Nakagami distribution fit]

However, when studying spacings $\Gamma(i+n)-\Gamma(i)$ with n=2,3,4...etc. Johnson distribution is superior. This is because skewness and kurtosis of the distributions change and Johnson (SB or SU) is very flexible distribution.

[image: First, second third and fourth spacings with Johnson SB distribtuion fits]

Answer (score 1):

Just looking at other distributions, the three-parameter Burr type XII distribution fits pretty well. Here's the result as above around $t_{1e9}$:

[image]

The Burr type XII pdf is:

$f(x|\alpha,c,k)={{kc\over \alpha}({x\over \alpha})^{c-1}\over{(1+({x\over a})^c)^{k+1}}}$

For the above fit,

$\alpha = 0.837947, c=2.76292$ and $k=8.68889 $

However, the best fit parameters change at other heights, e.g. at $t_{10e9}$:
[image]

$\alpha = 0.776292, c=2.73405$ and $k=9.38153 $

Note the mean has shifted down slightly. The mean is given by:

$\mu = \alpha k\Gamma(k-1/c)\Gamma(1+1/c)/\Gamma(k+1)$

The Burr type XII distribution is used most often to study mortality, survival, failure rates and the like. I guess the interval between a zeta zero and the next could be thought of as its lifespan.

Comment: Try setting c to exp(1) and fitting the other parameters